# Grep all files in a directory and print matches with filename

Tags: ubuntu, bash, find, grep, freebsd

I have a list of log files that I create as part of a video encoding script that I wrote.

I would like to search all of them and print out certain statistics from the encode - how fast they were encoded, what settings were used, etc.

I can search for the average framerate in one file via this 1 liner:

```
cat ${filename} | grep average
```

which outputs:

```
 work: average encoding speed for job is 23.211176 fps
```

and search for the ratefactor:

```
cat ${filename} | grep RF
```

I would like to search all files in the directory and print off one, or prefereably both pieces of information along with the filename. Is there any way I can use `find` or `grep` to get this in a one-liner, or do I need to write a script?

I would like output like this:

```
/home/javanix/filename.log
    <RF line>
    <average line>
```

I would like this to either work using FreeBSD 9 or Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Useless use of cat award! `grep something somewhere` is enough.

Comment: Haha, fair enough. I want a better solution, hence the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` with the desired output format:

```
awk '/average|RF/{ if(f!=FILENAME){f=FILENAME;print f} print"\t"$0}' *.log
```

For recursive search,

```
find path -name '*.log' -type f -exec \
  awk '/average|RF/{if(f!=FILENAME){f=FILENAME;print f}print"\t"$0}' {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
egrep 'RF|average' *
```

The output won't match the output you show above.  It will be like this:

```
filename1: ...
filename1: ...
filename2: ...
filename3: ...
```

Some file names will appear just once and some more, depending on how many matches there were.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you can do this with grep only:

```
grep -srHE 'average|RF' path/
```

`s` to suppress errors, `r` for recursive, `H` to display the filename and `E` (and the pipe) to match *any* of both patterns.

Comment: You're welcome, have a look at the answers using awk as you can get better formatting with it, even though the syntax is pretty obscure at first.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this one (although it seems the quickest for my use) is that it also outputs errors on files it can't read, and on files that seem to not be there during the command. +1 though

Comment: I just updated my post with the `s` flag :)

Comment: Confirmed: works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
grep -P "average|RF" *
```

`grep` will search in all files in the directory (`*`) and show all matches for the using the [Perl Compatible Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (PCRE) `average|RF`, which matches both `average` and `RF`.

The output format will be the following:

```
filename.log:<RF line>
filename.log:<average line>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner:

```
find -exec sh -c 'x=$(grep average "$0";grep RF "$0") && echo "$0\n$x"' {} \;
```

It will produce:

```
<file 1>
<RF line>
<average line>
[...]
```

As you can see there's no indentation to keep the code short, an alternative would be placing a mark on the file line, something like:

```
[...] echo ">>> $0\n$x"' {} \;
```